# Allocation of large amount of memory gives error ? Why?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have made a application for high resolution images.

when I want to allocate large amount of memory, the system says "Application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." 
But what I want is, the allocated pointer must return 0 Or NULL that I can show my message. It does not return zero/NULL why ? any idea? I checked with debug, before proceeding to MessageBox, it gives this error. what to do here to display my message ?

And is there a way to check that the user is going to allocate large enough memory than the computer PC capacity ?

Thanks.

```
ImageW = 2000;
ImageH = 2000;
point *Img = NULL;
Img = new point[ImageW*ImageH];
if(Img== NULL)
{   
MessageBox(0, "Your computer memory is too small.", "Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
return; 
}
```

Comment: Use nothrow version of new:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277637/new-stdnothrow-vs-new-within-a-try-catch-block

Comment: I pity the computer that doesn't have [what I imagine to be] 12MB spare of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [nothrow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow):

```
Img = new (nothrow) point[ImageW*ImageH];
//        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now you get a null pointer, rather than an exception, if the allocation failed.

Comment: yup.. nothrow is working.. but why visual stuio is creating a name.lib file in release folder. Is there any effect of this lip file when we build a setup MSI file. ?

Comment: @furqan: That is a completely unrelated question.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike `malloc` in C which returns `NULL` on failure, `new` in C++ can throw a std::bad_alloc exception which is what you're seeing. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new for reference

To handle this exception you can use try/catch:

```
try {
    Img = new point[ImageW*ImageH];
}
catch (std::bad_alloc const& e) {
    // handle failure here, like displaying a message
}
```

Here's documentation for the `std::bad_alloc` exception: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc

Comment: how to about this .. And is there a way to check that the user is going to allocate large enough memory than the computer PC capacity ? .. then what is the solution to display our own message ?

Comment: @furqan Edited my answer on how to handle this.

Comment: "You must use try/catch" Not true - look up `nothrow`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, I said "you must use try/catch" to handle the bad_alloc exception.

Comment: yea nothrow is working but creating a new name.lib file ? what is this.. and it will be included in the setup MSI build or not?

Answer (score 0):

C++ "new" does not return null on failure, it calls the new handler.